# How can I link my button from another page to a Boostrap tab?

Tags: jquery, tabs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-tabs

I know this question has been asked a bunch, but I can't seem to figure it out. I want the user to be able to click the button and jump to the correct bootstrap tab. I would prefer being able to directly link to the #whatsNew tabpanle, but I don't know if this is possible, so I have been trying to link it to the first tab "#stepOne". Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Font Awesome CDN -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">




</head>

<body id="learn">

  <!-- Nav Bar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-nav fixed-top fixed-top-1 navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">logo</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse1 navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- container -->
  </nav>
  
  <!--First set of Nav Tabs-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand bg-inverse navbar-inverse fixed-top fixed-top-2">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-left" id="navbar2">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active2" href="#overview" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#gettingStarted" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Getting Started</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#whatsNew" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">What's New</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <section id="subNavPanes">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane show fade active" id="overview">
        <header>

          <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
          <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron">
              <div class="row">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
          
          <!---Button I want to Link to What's New Tab-->
            <p class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-primary"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">See all the new features</a></button></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer>
    <p>footer</p>
  </footer>



  <!--The Nav Tab Page I'm trying to link to from the Overview Tab-->
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in" id="whatsNew">
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
          <div class="row">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <section id="section6" class="d-none d-md-block">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center bhoechie-tab-container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3 bhoechie-tab-menu">
                <div class="list-group .d-sm-block">
                  <a href="#stepOne" class="list-group-item active text-center">
                    <h4>Objective and quantified</h4>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#stepTwo" class="list-group-item text-center">
                    <h4>Objective and quantified</h4>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#stepThree" class="list-group-item text-center">
                    <h4>Objective and quantified</h4>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#stepFour" class="list-group-item text-center">
                    <h4>Objective and quantified</h4>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#stepFive" class="list-group-item text-center">
                    <h4>Objective and quantified</h4>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#stepSix" class="list-group-item text-center">
                    <h4>Objective and quantified</h4>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-9 bhoechie-tab text-center">
                <!-- flight section -->
                <div id="stepOne" class="bhoechie-tab-content active">

                  <img class="img-fluid " src="" alt="picture">
                  <div class="tab-text">
                    <h3>...</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- train section -->
                <div id="stepTwo" class="bhoechie-tab-content">

                  <img class="img-fluid" src="" alt="figure10">
                  <div class="tab-text">
                    <h3>...</h3>
                    <p>....</p>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>


  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer id="footer">
    <p>footer...</p>
  </footer>



  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.3.1/js/mdb.min.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this is a perfect scenario to provide a snippet, also your code is poorly formatted. these are aspects you should bare in mind in the future as they will get you lots more answers then how you posted your code

Comment: `href="#string"` will go to elements on the page that have an id matching that string.  Do your tabs have a matching id?

Comment: Also just for clarity, when you say "different tab", you're not talking about a browser tab, right?

Comment: Sorry about that, I have inserted a snippet. All my tabs work fine, just having trouble linking that button to that specific tab, not a browser tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an identifier on the button and assign a handler to its `.click()` inside which you manually trigger the desired tab's `.click()`.

HIH

```js
$('#gotonew').click(function(){
  $('a[href="#whatsNew"]').click();
  console.log($('a[href="#whatsNew"]').text() + ' click triggered');
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Font Awesome CDN -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">




</head>

<body id="learn">

  <!-- Nav Bar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-nav fixed-top fixed-top-1 navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">logo</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse1 navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- container -->
  </nav>
  
  <!--First set of Nav Tabs-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand bg-inverse navbar-inverse fixed-top fixed-top-2">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-left" id="navbar2">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active2" href="#overview" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#gettingStarted" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Getting Started</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#whatsNew" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">What's New</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <section id="subNavPanes">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane show fade active" id="overview">
        <header>

          <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
          <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron">
              <div class="row">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
          
          <!---Button I want to Link to What's New Tab-->
            <p class="text-center"><button id="gotonew" class="btn btn-primary"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">See all the new features</a></button></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer>
    <p>footer</p>
  </footer>



  <!--The Nav Tab Page I'm trying to link to from the Overview Tab-->
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in" id="whatsNew">
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
          <div class="row">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <section id="section6" class="d-none d-md-block">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center bhoechie-tab-container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3 bhoechie-tab-menu">
                <div class="list-group .d-sm-block">
                  <a href="#stepOne" class="list-group-item active text-center">
                    <h4>Objective and quantified</h4>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#stepTwo" class="list-group-item text-center">
                    <h4>Objective and quantified</h4>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#stepThree" class="list-group-item text-center">
                    <h4>Objective and quantified</h4>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#stepFour" class="list-group-item text-center">
                    <h4>Objective and quantified</h4>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#stepFive" class="list-group-item text-center">
                    <h4>Objective and quantified</h4>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#stepSix" class="list-group-item text-center">
                    <h4>Objective and quantified</h4>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-9 bhoechie-tab text-center">
                <!-- flight section -->
                <div id="stepOne" class="bhoechie-tab-content active">

                  <img class="img-fluid " src="" alt="picture">
                  <div class="tab-text">
                    <h3>...</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- train section -->
                <div id="stepTwo" class="bhoechie-tab-content">

                  <img class="img-fluid" src="" alt="figure10">
                  <div class="tab-text">
                    <h3>...</h3>
                    <p>....</p>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>


  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer id="footer">
    <p>footer...</p>
  </footer>



  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.3.1/js/mdb.min.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is there a way to load the new tab page starting from the top? When I scroll down and click the button it goes to the tab but I'm halfway down the page. You have helped me plenty so if you don't have the time no worries. I'm going to try and figure it out right now. Thaks again!